# Getting current time as output from "date" in awk script

Tags: awk, date, string

In an `awk`, script I am using a command

```
system(date)
```

to print the current date in a file, but after this command is executed, the next line is also added implicitly. Is there any way in `awk` to print the current date without the new line being added so that whatever I print next comes in the same line?

Answer (score 3):

The `date` command adds a newline at the end of its output. You can read the output into awk and make it print without appending a newline.

```
"date" | getline date; printf "%s", date
```

Unless your script is long-running, you could alternatively obtain the date when you start your script.

```
awk -v date="$(date)" '
    … printf "%s", date …
'
```

Comment: @Gilles-every thing is working fine but it gives an error /bin/sh: 1 :not found .I am using it like this:-

Comment: @Gilles-every thing is working fine but it gives an error /bin/sh: 1 :not found .I am using it like this:-   system("date"| getline date) printf("%s",date)

Comment: @nishan: The pipe executes its left-hand side as a command. So you're executing the result of `system(…)` as a shell command. The right syntax is in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The GNU `awk` and [@ThomasDickey](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/105132/thomas-dickey)'s `mawk` implementations of `awk` has some extensions relating to time and date functionality.  With these, you could use

```
strftime("%+", systime())
```

to get a string representation in the same format as the `date` utility would produce.

Or, for a slightly different format, but more portable (works on non-BSD systems),

```
strftime("%c", systime())
```

Testing:

```
$ date
Mon Jan 28 11:22:22 CET 2019
```

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN { print strftime("%+", systime()) }'
Mon Jan 28 11:22:27 CET 2019
```

```
$ mawk 'BEGIN { print strftime("%+", systime()) }'
Mon Jan 28 11:22:33 CET 2019
```

If the `%+` format is not supported on your system (it's not in `glibc2`), then `%c` would probably generate a close approximation to this.  The exact format will depend on the implementation of `strftime()` in the C library, and on the current datetime-related locale settings.  In the `C`/`POSIX` locale, you would get the same output as above, but with no time-zone abbreviation.

BSD `awk` implementation may not have these functions by default.

See also:

- The manuals for `awk` and `strftime` (for time/date-stamp formatting) on your system.

Comment: That would be @ThomasDickey's `mawk` (since 20121129). Note that the one that comes with Debian and derivatives doesn't have those extensions. `%+` support is also probably system dependant.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Some of that has now been addressed.  Thanks.